# Problems with a has_many - belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, belongs-to, model-associations

My data is basically Gallery(s) have many Picture(s), and Picture(s) belong_to a gallery. the pictures table has the foreign_key 'gallery_id'.

Although I`ve used has_many and belongs_to associations before, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

These are my relevant models:

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :pictures
    belongs_to :home
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :gallery
    validates :image, :presence => true
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader 
end
```

If I do this:

```
gallery = Gallery.create(:name => 'some name')
picture = Picture.create(:name => 'some name' , :image => 'some_image')
picture.gallery = gallery
```

this is true:

```
picture.gallery == @gallery
```

but this isnt

```
gallery.pictures == [ picture ]
```

because gallery.pictures returns an empty array.

On the other hand, if I create the picture this way, everything works as expected:

```
picture = Picture.create(:name => 'some name' , :image => 'some_image', :gallery_id => gallery)
```

Why? What I am doing wrong? I am using Rails 3.1.1 and sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should work

```
gallery.pictures.create :name => 'some name' , :image => 'some_image'
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding pictures to your gallery. Try doing the assignment the other way around.

```
gallery = Gallery.create(:name => 'some name')
picture = Picture.create(:name => 'some name' , :image => 'some_image')
gallery.pictures << picture
```

This will update the `#pictures` method to return the newly assigned picture.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I still dont understand why the code in my question doesnt work. Any clues?

Comment: Yeah because `gallery` needs to be reloaded from the database due to the way Rails caching the model. If you call `gallery.reload` after you assign picture to the gallery then all should work fine.